# Facebook integration using an existing Facebook application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated `Facebook` using `library` in my previous application and it works fine without any issues. But nowadays I want to integrate Facebook in my applications using an existing application.

When I click on `Facebook share icon` in my application it will check that you are already logged into your Facebook application which is already in your iPhone. If we are already logged in then the comment will be posted in our Facebook account. Otherwise the Facebook application will be open which is installed in our iPhone.

How can I make this possible?

I have seen this type of Facebook integration in [Path App](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/path/id403639508?mt=8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *[Facebook SDK for iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)* at the Facebook developer site. When you click share, you have to check it is a valid session using [Facebook isSessionValid].

If it is valid then you post the comment using the Facebook [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). If it is not, then you have to use the `[Facebook authorize:]` method.

Remember your application needs a Facebook ID in order to work.

Comment: 1490 thanx.. at above link at the bottom of the page "Hackbook' demo really nice which i m looking for ..